# angularjs ng-cloak is not working when page load

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ngcloak, async-loading

I am new to AngularJS and trying to fix the issue where some of the HTML code displays before ng-if condition gets evaluated. I am using ng-cloak as mentioned in many other stack over flow URLs but it still doesn't work for me. I am trying to load default image if actual image on URL is blank and when page loads, even if actual URL is there, it first blinks with default image and then loads the actual image because ng-cloak doesn't work correctly.

Please help.

I have below code and CSS etc.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <base href="/">

    <title>Some App</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
        display: none !important;
    }       
    </style>    
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
some code here
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

other.html

```
<div class="content">
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 40px;">

        <div ng-if="image.small">
            <img src="{image.small}}">
        </div>
        <div ng-if="!image.small" ng-cloak>
            <img src="image/default.png">
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use something like <img ng-src="{{image.small || 'image/default.png'}}"> to avoid using ngIf

Comment: @ItaloAyres, Thank you for answering but I need to use multiple conditions like if image.small is not there than check for image.large and if that is not there than load default image. Not sure how do I do that using this condition you have showed so I tried using ng-if for this.

Comment: Using || assignment it's a JS expression which returns the first not-null value. You can use it with any number of variables like this: X = a || b || c, and X would receive the first one with non null value.

Comment: So you can have something like: <img ng-src="{{ small || large || getImgSrc() || 'default.png'}}"> /* You can use functions in ngSrc as well */

Comment: @ItaloAyres I don't believe you. Show us a JSFiddle.

Comment: Haha, I like challenges. Wait for it. @georgeawg

Comment: [This may satisfy you](http://jsfiddle.net/hwzsgwtr/2). Feel free to modify the variables to see the results. @georgeawg

Comment: @ItaloAyres, yes after making these changes, it works fine for conditions but my concern is this default image still gets displayed earlier and than it replaced with actual image. ng-cloak is still not working. Please help there.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply `ng-cloak` in your `body` tag. So, you whole body will be displayed only after angular's compilation.

```
<body ng-cloak ng-app="app">
..
</body>
```

This will solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for answering @Abhilash P A but this is not working as well. After I apply ng-cloak in body tag, does this suppose to show some information related to this when I check on Developers tool on chrome? I see only <body ng-app="app" class="ng-scope"> in the developer tool even after adding ng-cloak as you have showed in example. One more questions is, do I need to load this ng-cloak as module similar to we add controller or service?

Comment: @ree, No, There is no module for `ng-cloak`. It is just a class with property `display:none` and after compilation angular's compiler will remove this class from the element.

Comment: So this is still not working for me. What should I do now. Please help. This is what exactly I have in my code now. <body ng-cloak ng-app="app">

Comment: @ree, remove your `style` part from the head. Because, angular.js will automatically generates this style for all pages. So no need to add this manually.

Comment: I have remove style from head and also added ng-show/ng-hide as mentioned here. I still have ng-cloak on body tag but still no luck. <div ng-show="image.small">
      <img ng-src="{{image.small}}">
     </div>
     <div ng-show="!image.small"  class="ng-hide">
      <img src="images/default.jpg">
     </div>

Comment: adding ng-cloak stopeed the whole page from being rendered @AbhilashAugustine

Comment: @user123456 Could you please inspect the html element where you have added ng-cloak? If it still have ng-cloak even after angular compilation, then probably Angular team has changed the behaviour. If there is no ng-cloak attribute then you should check for style property (display:none) for ng-cloak.

Answer (score 1):

I did it always on my `<html>` tag. Like `<html ng-app="someApp" ng-cloak>`

Answer (score 1):

The `timeout` function will do what you want:

```
// timeout function will give some time for page load.
$timeout(function () {
  //your page load
  $("#panelTask").html(res);
});
```

Comment: can you add some clarification?

Answer (score 0):

the best solution is to have a loader while your app is waiting for the data. Instead of putting the ng-if on the flickering element, put in on the parent component and show a loader (it could like FB does a sort of mock of your UI).

Answer (score 0):

I had to add :

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
display: none !important;
}
```

to my css file for ng-cloak to work.

Like here :[How to correctly use ng-cloak directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29339293/how-to-correctly-use-ng-cloak-directive)

Answer (score -3):

```
    <div ng-if="image.small">
        <img src="{image.small}}">
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!image.small" class="ng-cloak">
        <img src="image/default.png">
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you add more details to your answer? Makes it easier for OP to know what he have done wrong in his code :)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!