# Angular JS ng-cloak is not working properly expression symbol showing when page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am new to angular js and I am trying to fix the issue that some of the html code displays before it gets evaluated. It is first showing the expression and then the value. I have added ng-cloak in the body, but it is not working. I, then, tried to add it to the html top section, but no luck. Checked the below link:

[ng-cloak not working when page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33818166/ng-cloak-not-working-when-page-load)

but I am not able to find the correct solution for this.

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="rootApp" ng-cloak>
<div class="pName" ng-init="getDetails()">
                        <strong> {{desc}} <br>
                        {{shortdesc}} {{name}}</strong>
                    </div>
</body>
```

controller code:

```
$scope.getDetails = function () {
 // this is the  service call
        service.getName({ id: 3 }).$promise.then(function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $scope.desc = data[0].desc;
                $scope.shortdesc = data[0].shortdesc;
                $scope.name = data[0].name;
            }

        });

    }
```

Comment: In what position of the page are you loading angular? In the head, at the bottom of the page, async?

Comment: I am loading it in bottom of the page

Comment: You can put it in the head or use the css provided in the answers. If not, the page will be rendered before angular has a chance to hide it.

Answer (score 2):

when we use ng-cloak we put ng-Cloak in css please follow url 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Answer (score 1):

Include this CSS

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak
{
  display: none !important;
}
```

Even you need to wite `ng-cloak` inside `<strong>`

```
<strong ng-cloak>
```